# how to execute a python program (with args) that uses docker container?

Tags: python, docker, cmd, windows-11

First off, I might have formulated the question inaccurately, feel free to modify if necessary.

Although I am quite new to docker and all its stuff, yet somehow managed to create an image (`v2`) and a container (`cont`) on my Win 11 laptop. And I have a *demo.py* which requires an *.mp4* file as an arg.

Now, if I want to run the *demo.py* file, **1)** I go to the project's folder (where *demo.py* lives), **2)** open cmd and **3)** run: `docker start -i cont`. This starts the container as:

`root:834b2342e24c:/project#`

Then, I should copy **4)** *my_video.mp4* from local project folder to container's *project/data* folder (with another cmd) as follows:

`docker cp data/my_video.mp4 cont:project/data/`.

Then I run:  **5)** `python demo.py data/my_video.mp4`. After a while, it makes two files: *my_video_demo.mp4* and *my_video.json* in the data folder in the container. Similarly, I should copy them back to my local project folder: **6)**

`docker cp cont:project/data/my_video_demo.mp4 data/`, `docker cp cont:project/data/my_video_demo.json data/`

Only then I can go to my local *project/data* folder and inspect the files.
I want to be able to just run a particular command that does **4)** - **6)** all in one.
I have read about `-v`   option where, in my case, it would be(?) `-v /data:project/data`, but I don't know how to proceed.

Is it possible to do what I want? If everything is clear, I hope to get your support. Thank you.

Comment: Docker probably isn't the right tool for what you're describing, since a container doesn't usually have access to files outside the container.  Can you use a [Python virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/#creating-virtual-environments) instead?

Comment: I'd love to, but `demo.py` requires dependencies that are of Linux, not Windows. I tried building the project on Windows, but failed spectacularly :D.

Answer (score 0):

You should indeed use Docker volumes. The following command should do it.

```
docker run -it -v /data:project/data v2
```

Comment: 1. Where does it run the `demo.py` file? 2. Where are the output files get created?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I've come up with a way of dealing with it.

I have learned that with `-v` one can create a place that is shared between the local host and the container. All you need to do is that run the docker and provide `-v` as follows:

`docker run --gpus all -it -v C:/Workspace/project/data:/project/data v2:latest python demo.py data/my_video_demo.mp4`

`--gpus` - GPU devices to add to the container ('all' to pass all GPUs);

`-it` - tells the docker that it should open an interactive container instance.

Note that every time you run this, it will create a new container because of `-it` flag.

Partial credit to **@bill27**